# What is after second = in conda dependencies yml. Example pandas=1.2.4=py38h1abd341_0

Tags: anaconda, package, conda, conda-build

I am generating conda dependencies YAML and I don't entirely understand the information that is presented there. In `pandas=1.2.4=py38h1abd341_0` I know that it is pandas 1.2.4 version but what is `py38h1abd341_0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the build string, documented [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#build-number-and-string). The `py38` indicates the package is built for Python 3.8. The 8 characters after that are a hexidecimal hash of the package dependencies, to differentiate variants that can be used to satisfy different dependencies (think `glibc` on Linux or the [MSVCRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features?view=msvc-160) on Windows).

After the underscore is the build number, which is incremented when the package recipe changes but the package version does not change.

The new hash was introduced with [Conda Build 3](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/package-better-conda-build-3)